# How to change the row names in R data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, tidyverse

I would like to rename station in DF to something like `DA056` to `Happy` and `AB786` to `Sad`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF1 <- data.frame(Station = rep("DA056",3), Level = 100:102) 
DF2 <- data.frame(Station = rep("AB786",3), Level = 201:203) 
DF <- bind_rows(DF1,DF2)
```

Comment: In your case, `Station` are NOT row names. It is a separate column

Comment: Thanks @slava-kohut, i meant to change the unique `row name` under station column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `factor` with `labels` specified for corresponding `levels`

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- DF %>%
    mutate(Station = factor(Station, levels = c("DA056", "AB786"), 
              labels = c("Happy", "Sad")))

DF$Station
#[1] Happy Happy Happy Sad   Sad   Sad  
#Levels: Happy Sad
```

---

Or with `recode`

```
DF %>%
     mutate(Station = recode(Station, DA056 = 'Happy', AB786 = 'Sad'))
#  Station Level
#1   Happy   100
#2   Happy   101
#3   Happy   102
#4     Sad   201
#5     Sad   202
#6     Sad   203
```

---

If there are many values to be changed, a better option is a join after creating a key/val dataset

```
keyval <- data.frame(Station = c("DA056", "AB786"),
    val = c("Happy", "Sad"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF %>%
     left_join(keyval) %>%
     mutate(Station = coalesce(val, Station))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
DF$Station <- with(df,  factor(Station, levels = c("DA056", "AB786"), 
              labels = c("Happy", "Sad")))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `dplyr::case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 <- data.frame(Station = rep("DA056",3), Level = 100:102, stringsAsFactors = F) 
DF2 <- data.frame(Station = rep("AB786",3), Level = 201:203, stringsAsFactors = F) 
DF <- bind_rows(DF1,DF2)

DF <- DF %>% mutate(Station = case_when( Station == "DA056" ~ "Happy",
                                         Station == "AB786" ~ "Sad",
                                         TRUE ~ Station))
```

**Output**

```
> DF
  Station Level
1   Happy   100
2   Happy   101
3   Happy   102
4     Sad   201
5     Sad   202
6     Sad   203
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `case_when:`

```r
DF %>%
  mutate(Station = case_when(Station == "DA056"  ~ "Happy", Station =="AB786" ~ "Sad"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution

```
DF$Station = ifelse(DF$Station == "DA056", "Happy", "Sad")
```